# how to Add new Role employer also display in url like user/employer?

Tags: users

the default roles anonymous user, authenticated user, administrator and i want to add new role  employer i did it people -> permissions -> roles -> add roles.
i want to create new sign up **web form** that employer user ? and i want URL like user/employer

Comment: Hi Welcome to Drupal Answers :). Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Have you tried any of below modules mentioned in my answer @SkJani

Comment: thanks to giving suggestions but that modules are not work

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using any of below module :

1. [Registration role](https://www.drupal.org/project/registration_role) module. After register your self by user can directly assign the role.

> Registration role lets an administrator select a role to automatically
>   assign to new users. The selected role will be assigned to new
>   registrants.

2. [Webform Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_rules) module.

> This module adds rules integration on webforms. Webform Rules makes it
>   possible to catch webform submissions by rules and do whatever you'd
>   like to do with it.

3. [Auto Assign Role](https://www.drupal.org/project/autoassignrole) - This module definitely solve your both the issues i.e assigning role after registration & passing role on URL.

> The Auto Assign Role serves three primary purposes :
>
> 1. Provide an automatic assignment of roles when a new account is
>      created.
> 2. Allow the end user the option of choosing
>      their own role or roles when they create their account.
> 3. Provide paths that will trigger a specific role when an account is
>      created.

4. For the user/employer url you also do this by using [Path Auto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) module.

> The Pathauto module automatically generates URL/path aliases for
>   various kinds of content (nodes, taxonomy terms, users) without
>   requiring the user to manually specify the path alias. This allows you
>   to have URL aliases like /category/my-node-title instead of /node/123.
>   The aliases are based upon a "pattern" system that uses tokens which
>   the administrator can change.

5. [Multiforms](https://www.drupal.org/project/multiforms) module.

> The Multiforms module is designed for the collection of data from
>   users. It can be used to easily author multi-page forms which are
>   published as nodes. The data collected by the forms can then be
>   exported. It was originally designed to handle contest.

Comment: hi thanks to giving some information, and finally i got result i was using multi form module in that module i got result, thanks to reply to my questions